# Placing a character randomly in a bio-seq

Tags: matlab, alignment, bioinformatics

suppose that we have a bio_sequence like :

```
VYDDGYHNGN
```

and we're gonna place random number of '.' in random positions along the sequence, sth like this:

```
..VY.DD...GY..HN.GN..
```

is there any function or optimum solution for this task in MATLAB?

Comment: by random I mean a number between 0 to 0.2*length(sequence) which is selected randomly (Using rand() func.) and by random position I mean choosing one of all possible positions in a sequence.

Comment: With uniform distribution, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments, the following assumes that:

- The *total* number of dots is a random integer uniformly distributed between 0 and 0.2 times sequence length rounded to the nearest integer.
- Dot locations are also random and uniformly distributed.

Code:

```
%// Data
seq = 'VYDDGYHNGN';

%// Let's go
m = numel(seq); %// sequence length
n = randi([0 round(.2*m)]); %// number of dots
p = m+n;
result = repmat('.', 1, p); %// initiallize result to all dots
result(sort(randsample(p,m))) = seq; %// place sequence in uniformly random positions
```

Comment: thank you for answering :), I checked your code and it just change the order of letters in the sequence, it doesn't add any dots('.')!!!

Comment: @JalalAghazadeh I think this approach works too, if you run it for a number of times.

Comment: @JalalAghazadeh According to your specification, `0` is a possible value for the number of dots (in fact, in your example there can only be 0, 1 or 2 dots). As for the order change, you are right. I have corrected it

Answer (score 3):

`cumsum` based approach -

```
seq = 'VYDDGYHNGN'; %// Input sequence
N = numel(seq); %// number of elements in input sequence
grplen = ceil(0.2*N); %// group length
idx = cumsum(randi(grplen,1,N)) %// random indices for elements in output sequence
outseq = repmat('.',1, idx(end)+randi(grplen,1) ) %// placeholder for output
outseq(idx)=seq; %// Put elements from seq into outseq at random places indexed by idx
```

Sample output -

```
outseq =
V.YDDG.Y.H.NG.N.
```

Comment: +1 I see you have interpreted the "number" of dots as _each group_ (as opposed to _in total_). It probably makes more sense. The question is very unclear to me, anyway

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah it took me sometime to get into "mentalist" mode too, still not sure if OP needs it this way though! +1 already for you

Comment: thank you @Divakar :). I think this part of the code in line 3 n 4:{'randi(0.2*N,1,N))' & 'randi(0.2*N,1)'} should change to {'randi(ceil(0.2*N),1,N)' & 'randi(ceil(0.2*N)'}

Comment: @JalalAghazadeh Yeah that would make more sense. Edited the codes accordingly. Also, please consider accepting the solution that has best met the needs of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
sequence = 'VYDDGYHNGN';

factor = .2;

n = numel(sequence);
len = randi(n,n+1,1)-(1-factor)*n;

sequence = [sequence repmat('.',1,len(n+1))];
for idx = n:-1:1
    sequence= [sequence(1:idx-1) repmat('.',1,len(idx)) sequence(idx:end)];
end

sequence
```

---

Avoiding the loop can be done as follows:

```
sequence = 'VYDDGYHNGN';

factor = .2;

n = numel(sequence);
len = randi(n,n+1,1)-(1-factor)*n;

seqdot = repmat('.',1,n+sum(max(0,len)));
seqdot((1:n) + cumsum(max(0,len(1:end-1)))') = sequence;
```